# Clarification on custom init methods / pointers in general for objective c objects

Tags: objective-c, pointers, initialization

When I have my own init method with synthesized properties as such:

```
@property (copy, nonatomic)   NSString       *bookName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *book;
```

When I want to initialize with my own custom initializer I am shown to write it like this:

```
-(id) initWithName: (NSString *)name
{
    self = [super init]
    if (self) {
        bookName = [NSString stringWithString: name];
        book     = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Now I want to clarify something.  I know why it uses the stringWithString method, because instead of just passing the address to the passed in string it'll create a new object so that it owns the string itself.  Could I not also just write it like so:

```
self.bookName = name;
```

Doing this should use the synthesized method and actually create a new object right?  Basically both accomplish the same thing.  I ask because there are methods else where that show doing it both ways so I just want to make sure there are no other issues that could crop up with using one way or the other.  They both appear to do the same thing in different ways (using the synthesized method vs directly modifying the class variable but creating a new object in memory for it).

I'll also point out that this is in an ARC environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Note that I am assuming the above is ARC code; otherwise it is incorrect.)

You should almost always use accessors to access your ivars (even in ARC). However, there is some controversy about whether `init` should use accessors or directly access its ivars. I have switched sides in this controversy, but it's not an obvious decision IMO.

The primary argument for not allowing `init` to use accessors is that it is possible that a future (unknown) subclass might create side-effects in the accessor. You generally don't want side effects happening during your `init`. For instance, you probably don't want to post change notifications when you're setting something to its initial value, and it is possible that your object is in an "undefined state" and would be dangerous to read at this point.

That said, and while this argument did finally sway me, I have never once encountered this situation on numerous projects of various sizes with several teams. I have many times encountered developers failing to `retain` when setting their ivars in `init` (as you have done above, and which would crash if it is not ARC). This is why for a long time I recommended using accessors even in `init`. But in theory it does create a danger, particularly if you are a closed-source framework writer (i.e. Apple). And so, for my own code I now avoid accessors in `init`. If I were working with a more junior teams on older retain/release code, I would probably still have them use accessors in `init`. It's just avoided so many crashes in my experience.

It is not controversial that you should avoid calling accessors in `dealloc`, however. This definitely can lead to bizarre side-effects in the middle of destroying your object.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, since `bookName` is declared as `copy`, assigning `self.bookName` would make a *copy* of the string passed in. I am not certain that copying would go through exactly the same code path as the `[NSString stringWithString: name]`, but it would achieve the same purpose of creating a copy of the original string, shielding you from unexpected consequences of users passing in a mutable object and mutating its value behind your back.

Answer (score 1):

Because the declared property is `copy` then yes, they are doing the same thing.

Many times however, it is a `strong` and then there would be a difference between the two methods so the first method would be the "correct" way of doing it.